# write to file read operations

Tags: c#, file

I have to read text file that has millions of records. while reading file I have to implement something like "Tracker" which will write last read LineNumber to log file. I don't want this log file open and write operation affect my application performance. can anyone suggest me how to implement it?
P.S. I am using yield to read this big file, and I have multiple files like that. I want to stop reading operation if file has some invalid record...While this read operation is going on I want to somehow want to let end users know that so far it has read so and so number of line - file read is in progress.

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileNameAndPath))
                {
                    while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
                    {
                        string data = reader.ReadLine();

                        _fileLineNumber = _fileLineNumber + 1;
  //this line number should go to tracker file Logger.Trace(_fileLineNumber )

                       //............
                     }
                }
```

Logger class :

```
public static class Logger 
{     
      .....
      public static void Trace(string message)
      {
          FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append);
          StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
          streamWriter.WriteLine(message); 
      }

}
```

Comment: Just keep the streams open for the entirety of the application, or that read context. AKA don't have a static logger - inject it

Comment: Is that really your `Logger.Trace()` implementation? Because you're not closing the file stream...

Comment: Do you need to log the number of the last line you've read when the program finishes, or do you need to document each line you're read?

Comment: More ideally, don't do anything whilst you're trying to read out the rows. Either write every so often or until the operation finishes.

Comment: @CallumLinington: I edited my question. Please check. I want to keep track of how many lines I read so far.

Comment: @CallumLinington: can you explain why logger class or trace method should not be static?

Comment: @MatthewWatson: ya I am closing it....didn't mention in sample code

Comment: @falx: please read my additional comment. I need to document each line I read.

Comment: So, you can batch it up, so say every 1000 rows read, tell me. Why it should not be static... well, coupling, testability, liskov, ..... etc

Comment: I have a [repo](https://github.com/no1melman/ElasticSearchPopulator) that does all this. Have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your file stream as a class-level private field, open it before you enter your loop, then close it after you exit the loop.

Or better yet, implement `IDisposable` on `Logger`, and wrap your loop inside a `using` statement, and all the cleanup will take place automatically:

```
public class Logger : IDisposable
{
    private FileStream fileStream;
    private StreamWriter streamWriter;

    public void Trace(string message)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(message);
    }

    public Logger(string logFilePath)
    {
        fileStream = new FileStream(logFilePath, FileMode.Append);
        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        streamWriter.Dispose();
        fileStream.Dispose();
    }
}
```

here is how you would use it within the code you have:

```
var logFilePath = ""; // replace this with however you get your log path.

using (var logger = new Logger(logFilePath))
{
    while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        string data = reader.ReadLine();
        _fileLineNumber= _fileLineNumber + 1;
        logger.Trace(_fileLineNumber);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, I don't know what you're really trying to make but I suppose a best way to save that logging stuff is to write the file after your entire process. So, you can create an array of number and store that array once the process is done.

```
var readLines = new List<number>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_fileNameAndPath))
{
    while (reader.EndOfStream == false)
    {
        string data = reader.ReadLine();
        readLines.Add(_fileLineNumber);

        _fileLineNumber = _fileLineNumber + 1;
    }
}

Logger.Trace(readLines.ToString());
```